# Serializing double value to JSON string

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to serialize a double value 1.0 into JSON value 1.0. However, the following code outputs 1 instead of 1.0:

```
var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsSerializer.Serialize(1.0);
Console.WriteLine(json); // actual: 1, expected: 1.0
```

Does anyone has any idea how to accomplish this?

I though of creating a custom converter for double types by extending `JavaScriptConverter`, but the problem is the `Serialize` method is supposed to return `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: What's the difference? Isn't 1 and 1.0 the same as far as JSON is concerned? Javascript at least only has the type Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. All numbers in Javascript are floating point numbers (IEEE 754 double precision, to be exact): whether you say

- `var x = 1 ;`
- `var x = 1.0 ;`
- `{ x : 1 }`

the net result is the same: `x` is a floating point number with a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a specific text format for the value, you should serialize it as a string.  JSON isn't about text representation, it's about accurately serializing and deserializing values.  It only has one "Number" data type; if integer values lack a ".0" at the end, that's either because the specification says to do it that way or the specification leaves it to the implementation to decide.  The value of saving 2 characters per integer is probably significant in many applications.