# When / How to format decimal data type ASP.NET return JSON for use in datatables js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, datatables

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC . I am also using datatables.js . Because now I am using server side processing, I return JSON as data to the datatable.

`var jsonResult = Json(dataTableJsData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

I have decimal data type with two decimal places. So lets says I have a c# object with value of 80.00 But when the object is converted to JSON and transmitted over, the decimal place and the zeroes are stripped. That is the reason why the data that datatables.js receive is just 80 and display it.

I am confused as to how to format the results now. I have a hunch that I am suppose to format the data in ASP.NET first and then transmitting the data over. But I have no idea how to start.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you'll always want two decimal places, you can use [`number.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) in JavaScript. Or, you can pass it as a *string* from the server side so that trailing zeros are included, and then parse it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418260/serializing-double-value-to-json-string)  All numbers in Javascript are floating point numbers (IEEE 754 double precision, to be exact): whether you say

`var x = 1 ;
var x = 1.0 ;
{ x : 1 }`

so if you want a specific format then you need to cast in string